# Trying to use mark.js ES5 and ES6 version without JQuery, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I need a pure javascript plugin that works with IE 9+ to highlight a given regex expression. I found Mark.js and I managed to make it work, but not with the file recommended in the [docs](https://markjs.io/) that is inside the /dist/ folder.

I've tried with both 8.9.1 and 8.10.0 versions. [Download here](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/releases)

## How it worked

> 1 - Added the javascript library in the header tag. Note that this file is inside the src folder, not like recommended in the docs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/mark.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

> 2 - So, in the chrome developer tools console I've typed:

```
new Mark(document.querySelector("#div"));
```

> that works and give me this output:

```
Mark {ctx: null, ie: false}
```

## How it didn't work

> 1 - Added the javascript library in the header tag. Note that this file is inside the dist folder, like is said in the docs. I've tried with both  "*mark.es6.js*" and "*mark.js*", but what I really want to be working is the ES5 version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/mark.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

> 2 - So, in the chrome developer tools console I've typed:

```
new Mark(document.querySelector("#div"));
```

> this didn't work and give me this output:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Mark is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Are you sure you added your own script and the mark.js script in the right order ?

Comment: @Seblor It's in the same place, in both cases. My code don't have any call to mark.js functions, I called in from developer tools console. I've already checked if mark.js was loaded pressing Ctrl + P and typed mark.js, and it was.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the `mark.js` file you're adding ?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't have any 404 error ? Using a `/dist/` folder seems weird.

Comment: I've edited the question with the versions that I've tried and link to download. Actually, I changed a little the path in src because here I use a custom template tag (I don't know if it's the correct name) to get the path like:  <script type="text/javascript" src="../{#__MAINFOLDERPATH__#}/js/mark.js?TStamp=" charset="UTF-8"></script>

Comment: Is the file in the dist/ directory minified? Should it be src="dist/mark.min.js"?

Comment: the `dist` folder provided by APIs is usually the folder containing the **client** files to add. Just get the file(s) you need and put it (them) in the folder you want and then access it (them) from the html file.

Comment: @DonaldPowell No.

Comment: Provide a ZIP example with the folder you're trying to embed and the HTML that references that folder.

Comment: Or just the folders tree. There is the `tree` command on windows & unix consoles natively

Comment: I've figured out how to solve the problem, but I don't know the specific reason to the problem occur. I've create an empty .html importing just mark.js and it works. When I import the library converse.js before mark.js, it doesn't work. I was reading about the use of strict mode and thinking about it as the reason of the conflict, but I'm not sure.